# Can this question about the Sense Motive skill be reopened?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, closed-questions, duplicates

[This question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/156550/8610) for *Pathfinder* about how to use the Sense Motive skill is marked as a duplicate of [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/62166/8610) for *Dungeons & Dragons, 5th Edition* about how to use the Insight skill.

While these systems may seem similar enough and the advice offered by the answers  may be of interest to the *Pathfinder* question's asker, *Pathfinder* remains its own rule set.

I think the site suffers if questions about *one* game system are considered duplicates of questions about *entirely different* game systems. Also, I think a user's question about a system deserves to be addressed uniquely by experts in that system.

Can this question be reopened?

---

***Note:*** I suspect that a reason for closing the question as a duplicate may've been the assumption that there was no Pathfinder *answer to the question therefore redirecting the asker—and all subsequent readers of that question—to that* D&D 5e *question was seen as a favor, a way of giving the asker at least some advice on how to handle this unsolvable problem. However, if the problem* is *unsolvable in* Pathfinder *then the asker deserves to know that, and an answer should say as much… then that answer could direct the asker to that* D&D 5e *question and, perhaps, other questions on the site, too.)*

***Full Disclosure:*** I think that Pathfinder *question has a separate* Pathfinder *answer, but that answer involves the asker's table to undergo a paradigm shift that the group may find disrupts their current playstyle.*

Comment: Turns out that—surprise!—I possess sufficient privilege to reopen this question unilaterally. So I did. Yay, me.

Comment: Shazam! It's completed already, I wonder how...

Comment: Your superpowers leave me in awe. :)